# Protractor: Wait for image to load on Canvas

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, protractor

In Protractor, I need to open a non-angular page that has a canvas, which will be populated with an image.  I then need to manipulate the image and do a screenshot comparison.  However, my problem is getting the tests to wait for the image to load.  If I use the Expected Conditions to wait for element ie

```
browser.wait(expectedConditions.visibilityOf(element(by.tagName('canvas'), 20000);

browser.wait(expectedConditions.presenceOf(element(by.tagName('canvas'), 20000);
```

to be present or visible, the canvas element is present and visible, but the image is still loading into it, so the screenshot comparison fails as the image is usually half loaded when it happens.  I can ensure the image is fully loaded by inserting lots of browser.sleep(20000) statements in my code, but that's just horrible.

Does anyone know of a way to make protractor wait until the image has finished loading before continuing?  Or at least a slightly nicer way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Try listening to the canvas image you are loading (onload), instead than the canvas element itself... [HTML5 Canvas Image Tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/)

Comment: OK, that sounds good, but the tutorial doesn't really help me hook into the canvas image from protractor, how do I do that?  There doesn't really seem to be any way to grab it that I can find?

Comment: You could compare until var `c=document.getElementById("myCanvas"); c.toDataURL();` return the same2 or 3 times is just an idea, could be a work around or better give you ideas... I don't have a solid answer for now.

Comment: So just to clarify as I'm quite new to javascript and protractor.  So I'd pass these through to the browser using browser.executeScript as below, and I assume I can pass a lengthy script in doing this?  I'll have a play about.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by having a *custom Expected Condition*. I think you can use the `getImageData()` method of a canvas and wait for it to be truthy (not tested):

```
function waitForCanvasToLoad(elm) {
    return function () {
        return browser.executeScript("!!arguments[0].getImageData();", elm.getWebElement());
    }
}

var canvas = element(by.tagName('canvas'));
browser.wait(waitForCanvasToLoad(elm), 5000);
```

Comment: Cool, that looks like it may work, but it's giving me an out of memory error, I'll have a google around this, but if you have any suggestions they'd be most appreciated thanks.

Comment: @user3075259 I've applied a fix to the code (forgot to call `getWebElement()`), see if it helps. Also, play around with what you call on the canvas element - e.g. try `data` instead of `getImageData()`..

Comment: That works better, I'm not seeing any memory issues now, but it's also not returning anything and is just timing out.  I've tried returning pretty much everything I can.

Comment: @user3075259 okay, thanks, are you sure you are locating the correct `canvas` element?..

Comment: Yes, definitely getting the correct canvas element.  It seems to be working fine, but just times out.  even though the image has completely finished loading.  When I step through it it always returns null (I have added a then to the executeScript function to resolve the promise).

Answer (score 0):

You could wait for the encoded canvas to be just under the expected length:

```
var canvas = element(by.tagName('canvas'));
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(canvas), 6000);

// wait for the encoded length to be over 2500 (must be adjusted depending on the canvas)
browser.wait(() => browser.executeScript(
  (e) => e.toDataURL().length > 2500
  , canvas.getWebElement()), 6000);
```

You could also wait for the last pixel to be set if the color is not black:

```
var canvas = element(by.tagName('canvas'));
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(canvas), 6000);

// wait for the last pixel to be set (not black)
browser.wait(() => browser.executeScript(
  (e) => [].some.call(e.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.width, e.height, 1, 1), Math.abs)
  , canvas.getWebElement()), 6000);
```

Comment: Thanks, that almost looked like it would work, but in the end doesn't which is annoying, the canvas gets the full dataURL before it has finished drawing.  Looks like I'm stuck with browser.sleep.

Comment: In a testing context, I would compute the hash code of the canvas and wait until the expected hash is returned or until timeout.